# How to remove link from Wordpress menu icon?

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a menu on my Wordpress website that has both an icon and some text as the menu item. By default, both get wrapped by the `<a>` tag and work as links. Is there a way to have the link only on the text part and not the icon? This is how the menu item is set up:

[image: menu icon]

And this is what I would like to achieve:

[image: menu item html]

Any idea if this is even possible within the limits of the basic Wordpress menu functionality?

Comment: The approach will be to have a child theme of your theme. 
Then replicated header in child theme. 
Then update the code that is generating the html of menu.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around the issue: every menu item in WordPress has the option of custom CSS tags (if you can't see it, you have to enable it in the screen options). So what I did is simply remove all icons from all menu items and instead used a custom CSS class that added the same icon as a background image, along with some padding on the left, so the image isn't displayed behind the text.

This worked out perfectly because I was using the same icon for many different menu items. I'm guessing that if you have different icons, this approach won't work.

The `<a>` tag now includes only text, since there is no `<img>` tag anymore.